# Ubuntu 19.10 Dell XPS13, wifi unusable

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet, 19.10

I'm still struggling with the Wi-Fi on my XPS13 since upgrading to 19.10.

It is basically unusable with constant drop outs and lockups of the system when trying to fix the issue.

The end of `syslog` when it drops out looks like this:

```
Nov  7 18:49:26 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 NetworkManager[486]: <info>  [1573112966.4328] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): state changed bound -> bound                                                                              
     1 Nov  7 18:49:26 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 dbus-daemon[1261]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.1051'        (uid=0 pid=486 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
     2 Nov  7 18:49:26 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
     3 Nov  7 18:49:26 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 dbus-daemon[1261]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
     4 Nov  7 18:49:26 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
     5 Nov  7 18:49:37 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Succeeded.
     6 Nov  7 18:50:14 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 systemd-resolved[1114]: Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server 8.8.8.8.
     7 Nov  7 18:50:19 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 systemd-resolved[1114]: Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server 192.231.203.132.
     8 Nov  7 18:50:20 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 systemd-resolved[1114]: Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server 192.231.203.3.
     9 Nov  7 18:50:20 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 systemd-resolved[1114]: Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server fe80::a691:b1ff:fe7d:fbad%2.
    10 Nov  7 18:50:27 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 systemd-resolved[1114]: Using degraded feature set (TCP) for DNS server 8.8.8.8.
    11 Nov  7 18:50:28 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 systemd-resolved[1114]: Using degraded feature set (TCP) for DNS server fe80::a691:b1ff:fe7d:fbad%2.
    12 Nov  7 18:50:30 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 systemd-resolved[1114]: Using degraded feature set (TCP) for DNS server 192.231.203.132.
    13 Nov  7 18:50:32 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 systemd-resolved[1114]: Using degraded feature set (TCP) for DNS server 192.231.203.3.
    14 Nov  7 18:50:58 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 systemd-resolved[1114]: Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server 192.231.203.132.
    15 Nov  7 18:51:01 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 systemd-resolved[1114]: Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server 8.8.8.8.
    16 Nov  7 18:51:03 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 systemd-resolved[1114]: Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server 192.231.203.3.
    17 Nov  7 18:51:06 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 systemd-resolved[1114]: Using degraded feature set (TCP) for DNS server 192.231.203.132.
    18 Nov  7 18:51:09 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 systemd-resolved[1114]: Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server fe80::a691:b1ff:fe7d:fbad%2.
    19 Nov  7 18:51:11 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 systemd-resolved[1114]: Using degraded feature set (TCP) for DNS server 8.8.8.8.
    20 Nov  7 18:51:11 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 systemd-resolved[1114]: Using degraded feature set (TCP) for DNS server 192.231.203.3.
    21 Nov  7 18:51:12 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 systemd-resolved[1114]: Using degraded feature set (TCP) for DNS server fe80::a691:b1ff:fe7d:fbad%2.
    22 Nov  7 18:51:15 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 systemd-resolved[1114]: Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server 192.231.203.132.
    23 Nov  7 18:51:16 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 gnome-shell[3818]: libinput error: client bug: timer event7 tap: offset negative (-597ms)
    24 Nov  7 18:51:16 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 gnome-shell[3818]: libinput error: client bug: timer event7 tap: offset negative (-478ms)
    25 Nov  7 18:51:16 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 gnome-shell[3818]: libinput error: client bug: timer event7 tap: offset negative (-91ms)
    26 Nov  7 18:51:18 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 kernel: [24948.086310] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: wmi command 16387 timeout, restarting hardware
    27 Nov  7 18:51:18 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 kernel: [24948.086324] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to set 5g txpower 30: -11
    28 Nov  7 18:51:18 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 kernel: [24948.086327] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to setup tx power 30: -11
Nov  7 18:51:18 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 kernel: [24948.086330] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to recalc tx power: -11
    38 Nov  7 18:51:18 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 kernel: [24948.086504] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to set inactivity time for vdev 0: -108
    37 Nov  7 18:51:18 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 kernel: [24948.086509] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to setup powersave: -108
    36 Nov  7 18:51:18 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 kernel: [24948.086549] wlp2s0: deauthenticating from 74:83:c2:38:26:87 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
    35 Nov  7 18:51:18 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 kernel: [24948.097051] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to read hi_board_data address: -16
    34 Nov  7 18:51:19 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 systemd-resolved[1114]: Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server 192.231.203.3.
    33 Nov  7 18:51:21 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 kernel: [24951.143224] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to receive initialized event from target: 00000000
    32 Nov  7 18:51:22 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 systemd-resolved[1114]: Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server 8.8.8.8.
    31 Nov  7 18:51:24 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 kernel: [24954.171078] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to receive initialized event from target: 00000000
    30 Nov  7 18:51:24 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 kernel: [24954.171082] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to wait for target init: -110
    29 Nov  7 18:51:24 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 kernel: [24954.172951] ieee80211 phy0: Hardware restart was requested
    28 Nov  7 18:51:24 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 kernel: [24954.173007] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to set inactivity time for vdev 0: -108
    27 Nov  7 18:51:24 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 kernel: [24954.173009] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to setup powersave: -108
    26 Nov  7 18:51:24 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 kernel: [24954.173012] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to set PS Mode 0 for vdev 0: -108
    25 Nov  7 18:51:24 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 kernel: [24954.173013] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to setup powersave: -108
    24 Nov  7 18:51:24 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 kernel: [24954.173014] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to setup ps on vdev 0: -108
    23 Nov  7 18:51:24 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 kernel: [24954.173109] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to flush transmit queue (skip 1 ar-state 2): 1250
    22 Nov  7 18:51:24 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 kernel: [24954.173300] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to delete peer 74:83:c2:38:26:87 for vdev 0: -108
    21 Nov  7 18:51:24 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 kernel: [24954.173380] WARNING: CPU: 2 PID: 486 at net/mac80211/sta_info.c:1057 __sta_info_destroy_part2+0x178/0x180 [mac80211]
    20 Nov  7 18:51:24 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 kernel: [24954.173381] Modules linked in: usbhid ccm thunderbolt rfcomm nf_conntrack_netlink nfnetlink xfrm_user xfrm_algo xt_CHECKSUM xt_MASQUERADE xt_addrtype xt_connt       rack br_netfilter ipt_REJECT nf_reject_ipv4 xt_tcpudp ip6table_mangle ip6table_nat iptable_mangle iptable_nat nf_nat nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 libcrc32c ebtable_filter ebtables ip6table_       filter ip6_tables iptable_filter bpfilter bridge stp llc pci_stub cmac vboxpci(OE) vboxnetadp(OE) vboxnetflt(OE) vboxdrv(OE) aufs overlay bnep uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 b       tusb videobuf2_common btrtl btbcm videodev btintel mc bluetooth cdc_acm ecdh_generic ecc binfmt_misc snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_soc_skl mei_hdcp snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_skl_ipc snd_soc_sst_       ipc snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_soc_sst_dsp snd_hda_codec_generic snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_soc_acpi snd_soc_core snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hwd       ep intel_rapl_msr snd_pcm
    19 Nov  7 18:51:24 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 kernel: [24954.173412]  ath10k_pci ath10k_core snd_seq_midi joydev snd_seq_midi_event dell_laptop snd_rawmidi x86_pkg_temp_thermal ath ledtrig_audio intel_powerclamp snd       _seq mac80211 kvm_intel snd_seq_device snd_timer kvm snd irqbypass dell_wmi dell_smbios intel_cstate dcdbas mei_me intel_rapl_perf cfg80211 soundcore input_leds serio_raw wmi_bmof rtsx_pci_ms libarc4 del       l_wmi_descriptor intel_wmi_thunderbolt mei idma64 ucsi_acpi intel_xhci_usb_role_switch memstick hid_multitouch virt_dma typec_ucsi roles processor_thermal_device typec intel_rapl_common intel_hid int3403       _thermal intel_pch_thermal intel_soc_dts_iosf int3400_thermal int340x_thermal_zone acpi_thermal_rel acpi_pad mac_hid sparse_keymap sch_fq_codel coretemp parport_pc ppdev lp parport sunrpc ip_tables x_tab       les autofs4 dm_crypt hid_generic i915 crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel i2c_algo_bit rtsx_pci_sdmmc aesni_intel drm_kms_helper aes_x86_64 crypto_simd syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt cry       ptd fb_sys_fops glue_helper
    18 Nov  7 18:51:24 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 kernel: [24954.173452]  psmouse nvme drm i2c_i801 nvme_core intel_lpss_pci rtsx_pci intel_lpss i2c_hid hid wmi pinctrl_sunrisepoint video pinctrl_intel
    17 Nov  7 18:51:24 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 kernel: [24954.173461] CPU: 2 PID: 486 Comm: NetworkManager Tainted: G           OE     5.3.0-19-generic #20-Ubuntu
    16 Nov  7 18:51:24 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 kernel: [24954.173462] Hardware name: Dell Inc. XPS 13 9370/0F6P3V, BIOS 1.11.1 07/11/2019
    15 Nov  7 18:51:24 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 kernel: [24954.173481] RIP: 0010:__sta_info_destroy_part2+0x178/0x180 [mac80211]
    14 Nov  7 18:51:24 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 kernel: [24954.173483] Code: 24 0c 01 00 00 00 0f 84 28 ff ff ff 45 31 c0 b9 01 00 00 00 4c 89 e2 48 89 de 4c 89 ef e8 80 a6 ff ff 85 c0 0f 84 0a ff ff ff <0f> 0b e9 03        ff ff ff 90 0f 1f 44 00 00 55 48 89 e5 41 55 49 89 fd
    13 Nov  7 18:51:24 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 kernel: [24954.173484] RSP: 0018:ffffabd9c1607940 EFLAGS: 00010282
    12 Nov  7 18:51:24 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 kernel: [24954.173486] RAX: 00000000ffffff94 RBX: ffff9222103988c0 RCX: 0000000000000000
    11 Nov  7 18:51:24 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 kernel: [24954.173487] RDX: ffff921effcc8000 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: ffff922212df2e38
    10 Nov  7 18:51:24 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 kernel: [24954.173488] RBP: ffffabd9c1607960 R08: ffff92221e897448 R09: 0000000000000004
     9 Nov  7 18:51:24 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 kernel: [24954.173488] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: ffff9221f8b20000
     8 Nov  7 18:51:24 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 kernel: [24954.173489] R13: ffff922212df07a0 R14: ffff9222103988c0 R15: ffff922212df0d58
     7 Nov  7 18:51:24 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 kernel: [24954.173491] FS:  00007f6b5fa5bbc0(0000) GS:ffff92221e880000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
     6 Nov  7 18:51:24 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 kernel: [24954.173492] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
     5 Nov  7 18:51:24 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 kernel: [24954.173493] CR2: 000009b84bc7d000 CR3: 0000000493372001 CR4: 00000000003606e0
     4 Nov  7 18:51:24 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 kernel: [24954.173494] Call Trace:
     3 Nov  7 18:51:24 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 kernel: [24954.173512]  __sta_info_flush+0x123/0x170 [mac80211]
     2 Nov  7 18:51:24 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 kernel: [24954.173535]  ieee80211_set_disassoc+0xc7/0x5d0 [mac80211]
     1 Nov  7 18:51:24 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 kernel: [24954.173557]  ieee80211_mgd_deauth+0x104/0x460 [mac80211]
891981 Nov  7 18:51:24 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 kernel: [24954.173576]  ieee80211_deauth+0x18/0x20 [mac80211]    
 Nov  7 18:51:24 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 kernel: [24954.173607]  cfg80211_mlme_deauth+0xb6/0x1e0 [cfg80211]                                                                                                       
     1 Nov  7 18:51:24 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 kernel: [24954.173628]  cfg80211_mlme_down+0x66/0x80 [cfg80211]
     2 Nov  7 18:51:24 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 kernel: [24954.173681]  cfg80211_disconnect+0x127/0x1e0 [cfg80211]
     3 Nov  7 18:51:24 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 kernel: [24954.173685]  ? _raw_spin_unlock_bh+0x1e/0x20
     4 Nov  7 18:51:24 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 kernel: [24954.173696]  __cfg80211_leave+0x133/0x1b0 [cfg80211]
     5 Nov  7 18:51:24 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 kernel: [24954.173705]  cfg80211_leave+0x2c/0x40 [cfg80211]
     6 Nov  7 18:51:24 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 kernel: [24954.173714]  cfg80211_netdev_notifier_call+0x1b1/0x510 [cfg80211]
     7 Nov  7 18:51:24 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 kernel: [24954.173716]  ? _cond_resched+0x19/0x30
     8 Nov  7 18:51:24 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 kernel: [24954.173717]  ? __mutex_lock.isra.0+0x37/0x4f0
     9 Nov  7 18:51:24 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 kernel: [24954.173720]  ? wake_up_q+0x40/0x70
    10 Nov  7 18:51:24 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 kernel: [24954.173721]  ? wake_up_q+0x40/0x70
    11 Nov  7 18:51:24 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 kernel: [24954.173724]  ? inetdev_event+0x46/0x570
    12 Nov  7 18:51:24 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 kernel: [24954.173726]  ? skb_dequeue+0x5a/0x70
    13 Nov  7 18:51:24 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 kernel: [24954.173728]  notifier_call_chain+0x55/0x80
    14 Nov  7 18:51:24 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 kernel: [24954.173730]  raw_notifier_call_chain+0x16/0x20
    15 Nov  7 18:51:24 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 kernel: [24954.173732]  call_netdevice_notifiers_info+0x2e/0x60
    16 Nov  7 18:51:24 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 kernel: [24954.173733]  __dev_close_many+0x63/0x120
    17 Nov  7 18:51:24 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 kernel: [24954.173734]  dev_close_many+0x91/0x150
    18 Nov  7 18:51:24 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 kernel: [24954.173735]  dev_close.part.0+0x4a/0x70
    19 Nov  7 18:51:24 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 kernel: [24954.173737]  dev_close+0x18/0x20
    20 Nov  7 18:51:24 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 kernel: [24954.173745]  cfg80211_shutdown_all_interfaces+0x77/0xd0 [cfg80211]
    21 Nov  7 18:51:24 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 kernel: [24954.173754]  cfg80211_rfkill_set_block+0x26/0x30 [cfg80211]
    22 Nov  7 18:51:24 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 kernel: [24954.173756]  rfkill_set_block+0x9b/0x150
    23 Nov  7 18:51:24 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 kernel: [24954.173758]  rfkill_fop_write+0x136/0x1e0
    24 Nov  7 18:51:24 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 kernel: [24954.173760]  __vfs_write+0x1b/0x40
    25 Nov  7 18:51:24 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 kernel: [24954.173762]  vfs_write+0xb9/0x1a0
    26 Nov  7 18:51:24 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 kernel: [24954.173764]  ksys_write+0xb1/0xe0
    27 Nov  7 18:51:24 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 kernel: [24954.173765]  __x64_sys_write+0x1a/0x20
    28 Nov  7 18:51:24 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 kernel: [24954.173768]  do_syscall_64+0x5a/0x130
    29 Nov  7 18:51:24 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 kernel: [24954.173770]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xa9
    30 Nov  7 18:51:24 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 kernel: [24954.173771] RIP: 0033:0x7f6b6109327f
    31 Nov  7 18:51:24 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 kernel: [24954.173773] Code: 89 54 24 18 48 89 74 24 10 89 7c 24 08 e8 19 fd ff ff 48 8b 54 24 18 48 8b 74 24 10 41 89 c0 8b 7c 24 08 b8 01 00 00 00 0f 05 <48> 3d 00 f0        ff ff 77 2d 44 89 c7 48 89 44 24 08 e8 4c fd ff ff 48
    32 Nov  7 18:51:24 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 kernel: [24954.173774] RSP: 002b:00007ffd34ea4150 EFLAGS: 00000293 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000001
    33 Nov  7 18:51:24 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 kernel: [24954.173775] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 0000562fafc0ff85 RCX: 00007f6b6109327f
    34 Nov  7 18:51:24 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 kernel: [24954.173776] RDX: 0000000000000008 RSI: 00007ffd34ea4188 RDI: 0000000000000018
    35 Nov  7 18:51:24 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 kernel: [24954.173776] RBP: 0000000000000018 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000001
    36 Nov  7 18:51:24 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 kernel: [24954.173777] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000293 R12: 0000562fb0c50090
    37 Nov  7 18:51:24 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 kernel: [24954.173777] R13: 0000000000000000 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: 0000562fb0c4ac20
    38 Nov  7 18:51:24 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 kernel: [24954.173779] ---[ end trace 42a6c3ea575789be ]---
    39 Nov  7 18:51:24 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 kernel: [24954.173839] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to recalculate rts/cts prot for vdev 0: -108
    40 Nov  7 18:51:24 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 kernel: [24954.173840] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to set cts protection for vdev 0: -108
Nov  7 18:51:24 pnunn-XPS-13-9370 wpa_supplicant[1263]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=74:83:c2:38:26:87 reason=3 locally_generated=1
     7 ^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^       @^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@       ^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^       @^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@       ^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^       @^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@       ^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^       @^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@       ^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^       @^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@       ^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^       @^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@       ^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^       @^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@       ^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
```

Sometimes I can restart it by turning the Wi-Fi on and off, other times by putting it into air plane mode, however, most times it just locks up the whole system when I try and repair it.

I have installed the latest ath10K driver (bin-2) from the git repo but that didn't help.

Any ideas how to sort this?

More Info. This looks to be some sort of timeout. Interestingly if I stream something on the wifi, it does not seem to drop out. It only turns off if there is no real activity on the wifi (ping doesn't seem to be enough to keep it alive).

Still more info... this DOES NOT happen with Fedora 31 live CD. Hmmm...

Answer (score 0):

Just as I was about to blow Ubuntu away and install Fedora, I came across this solution.

It seems the solution is to follow the instructions here...

[Killer N1535 Wireless Firmware Manual Update Guide for Ubuntu Systems](https://www.dell.com/support/article/au/en/aubsd1/sln306440/killer-n1535-wireless-firmware-manual-update-guide-for-ubuntu-systems?lang=en)

Followed these instructions, and now, apart from the icon showing with a ? in it after a sleep... the wifi seems to be staying connected.